# Quarto fails to pass author metadata when output is pdf

Tags: r, pandoc, quarto

In a .qmd file it is possible to add metadata to authors, like email, affiliations, *etc*,  following a template as explained here: https://quarto.org/docs/journals/authors.html#author-schema.

When I render the document to pdf, these author-related metadata do not appear in the final document. In fact they are converted into `true` statements that can be found as is in the .tex file.

How to successfully pass author metadata to the pdf output?

Here is a minimalist YALM that reproduce the problem:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: 
  - name:
      given: Norah
      family: Jones
      literal: Norah Jones
format:
  pdf: default
editor: visual
---
```

If I render this YALM in a .qmd file, I get the following output:
[image]

Further investigation in the .tex file generated during the transformation process shows that the value `true` is passed into the latex command `\author{true}` (line 146). Am I missing something?

However, if the author name is passed like below, it seems to work but then how to pass other metadatas such as email, *etc.* ?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: 
  - name: Norah Jones
format:
  pdf:
    keep-md: true
    keep-tex: true
editor: visual
---
```

[image]

Comment: Affiliations isn't standard in Quarto pdf. Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040607/why-do-affiliations-not-show-up-anywhere-in-the-pdf-output-of-quarto;

Comment: See this extension: https://github.com/kapsner/authors-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was identified as a bug: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/3483 and is still around in version Quarto v1.2.335.
However, it is fixed in the pre-release version v1.3.269; "Fix author processing in default PDFs for complex author names (#3483)".

Updating the version of Quarto from v1.2.335 to v1.3.269 fixed the problem.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: 
  - name:
      given: Norah
      family: Jones
format:
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
editor: visual
---
```

[image]