# Why do the same affiliation is repeated in the pdf output of quarto?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, pandoc, quarto

The quarto document **quarto-file.md** repeats the same affiliations:

```
---
title: "Hey!"
author:
  - name: Birdy Bird
    affiliations:
      - University of Birds
  - name: None
    affiliations:
      - University of Birds
format: 
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    template-partials: 
      - title.tex
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
        \renewcommand*{\Authsep}{, }
        \renewcommand*{\Authand}{, }
        \renewcommand*{\Authands}{, }
        \renewcommand\Affilfont{\small}
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished
document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

[image: quarto-file-render]

I want the same affiliations not to be repeated, but this does not work using the **title.tex** in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75043433/6832021) to a similar question:

```
$if(title)$
\title{$title$$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}
$endif$

$if(subtitle)$
\subtitle{$subtitle$}
$endif$

$for(by-author)$
\author[$for(by-author.affiliations)$$it.number$$sep$,$endfor$]{$by-author.name.literal$}
$endfor$

$for(by-author)$
$if(by-author.affiliations)$
$for(by-author.affiliations)$
\affil[$it.number$]{$if(by-author.affiliations.name)$$by-author.affiliations.name$$endif$}
$endfor$
$endif$
$endfor$


\date{$date$}
```

How to make the same affiliations to appear only once (with the same superscript)?

Comment: What is the quarto version you are using?

Comment: I'm using quarto ‘1.3.319’ from RStudio

Comment: Okay, I think, Quarto version 1.3.x support [authors affiliations](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/authors.html#inline-affiliations).

Comment: I read the same, but it does not add the affiliations without using either the title.tex partial or the author-block lua filter

Comment: Okay, thats odd. I thought quarto 1.3.x fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of [authors-block](https://github.com/kapsner/authors-block) has a major flaw in that, it adds the affiliations in the document body not in the document preamble (which you can verify if you look into the underlying tex file) which results in a large gap between the authors name and affiliations and also if you use abstract, the affiliations will be positioned after the abstract, which is visually not good.

Therefore, I think, the use of `title.tex` latex-partial to accommodate the `authblk` latex package should be preferable for proper and nice formatting of the affiliations.

Now the key thing to note that the option `affil-id` which needs to be a number that will link the authors and their affiliations and it will correspond to the `id` under the `affiliations` key.

```
---
title: "Hey!"
abstract: This is the abstract of the document. And you can see the author affiliations is nicely formatted.
author:
  - name: Birdy Bird
    affil-id: 1
  - name: None
    affil-id: 1

affiliations: 
  - id: 1
    name: University of Birds
format: 
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    template-partials: 
      - title.tex
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
        \renewcommand*{\Authsep}{, }
        \renewcommand*{\Authand}{, }
        \renewcommand*{\Authands}{, }
        \renewcommand\Affilfont{\small}
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished
document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

**title.tex**

```
$if(title)$
\title{$title$$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}
$endif$

$if(subtitle)$
\subtitle{$subtitle$}
$endif$

$for(by-author)$
\author$if(it.metadata.affil-id)$[$it.metadata.affil-id$]$endif${$it.name.literal$}
$endfor$

$if(by-affiliation)$
$for(by-affiliation)$
\affil[$it.id$]{$it.name$}
$endfor$
$endif$


\date{$date$}
```

---

[image: Nicely formatted author affiliations]

---

And to add multiple affiliations per author, specify the affiliation `id` numbers (comma separated) in the `affil-id` key. See the [updated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75043433/10858321) for example.

Comment: Thanks, @shafee! This is a more straightforward answer to the OP. I agree with the problematic distance from authors and the affiliations using `authors-block`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [authors-block](https://github.com/kapsner/authors-block) extension, e.g.

```
---
title: "Hey!"
authors:
  - name: Birdy Bird
    affiliations:
      - ref: bird
  - name: None
    affiliations:
      - ref: bird

affiliations:
  - id: bird
    name: University of Birds.
      
filters:
  - authors-block

format: pdf
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished
document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but I get an output without the authors' names, only with the affiliation. This may be due to the fact that I "manually" installed the authors-block extension (copying the lua filters from the repo), as I couldn't find a way to install extensions in RStudio

Comment: you can use the terminal to install extension.

Comment: It finally worked, thanks. I had missed that for quarto >=1.3 one should install the extension with `quarto add kapsner/authors-block@v0.2.0`

Comment: **Note:  `authors-block` adds the authors' affiliation info in the document body, not in the document preamble and it leads to a big gap between the authors and affiliations. Also if you use an abstract, the affiliations will be positioned after the document abstract.** (And I think, this extension is intended for docx file, not for pdf output)