# Why can't I add email in my quarto document (pdf)

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto

This is literally copy-pasted from Quarto's webpage! I have updated to the latest version of Rstudio. Here's a code and a screenshot:

````
---
format: pdf
title: "Your Title"
author:
  - name: Bill Gates
    email: bill@gates.com
---

```{r}
mtcars
```
````

[image]

How can I get it to print the email?

Comment: Try previewing in `format: jats` - if it appears there, then it's due to the PDF output setup, rather than your code.  If it's missing then there must be something awry in the code.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a bit? I tried ````format: jats````, but nothing changed. So it's there something wrong with my code? I don't see how?

Comment: Sorry, I am not at a location where I can test a Quarto output, it was just an idea to help diagnose the issue - hopefully someone better placed will be along to help.

Comment: which quarto version are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040607/why-do-affiliations-not-show-up-anywhere-in-the-pdf-output-of-quarto

Comment: I have ver. 1.3.433. I can't see where it says it's related to the version??